# Is there a distribution-independent tool to autocompile+install dependencies?

Tags: utilities, dependencies, source

I like the way e.g. ArchLinux' [`yaourt`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Yaourt) (or if you're not that lazy, `abs`+`makepkg`; and from what I read so far, Gentoo's [`ebuild`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ebuild) as well) automatically take care of obtaining, compiling and installing dependencies (and *their* dependencies etc.) before compiling a desired package. Currently I'm working with a system that does not natively provide such a mechanism (a [Buffalo LinkStation Pro Duo](http://buffalo.nas-central.org/wiki/Category%3aLS-WVL) with root access via ssh) and need to compile some programs with horribly complex dependency chains, crawling through which manually is really tedious, so I'm wondering if there either is

- a tool similar to the aforementioned ones, which basically takes a sourcecode directory (or `.tar.gz` or git-repo or ...) and before compiling checks for missing dependencies, more or less automatically obtains their sourecode (recursing until all dependencies are resolved)
- a way to configure one of these tools such that they respect deviations from their own distribution, e.g. installing everything under `/opt` and not attempting to upgrade the (firmware-specific) kernel?

Sure enough there are many peculiarities in the general case, but for the sake of it assume 90% of all dependencies merely require a `./configure --prefix=/opt && make && make install` run.

Comment: Such tools always have to be distribution specific or will not work as well as they should.

Comment: There might be some tuning required, but assuming all I'd manually have to do after locating the source would be `./configure --prefix=/opt && make && make install` in most cases, this should be quite automate-able

Comment: Maybe interesting approach/inspiration: [Rootless GoboLinux](http://www.gobolinux.org/?page=rootless) and [its recipe system](http://www.gobolinux.org/?page=doc/articles/compile)

Comment: Have you considered debootstrap-ping a Debian derived distribution in there and use it over chroot (or LXC if the buffalo kernel has it enabled)?

Comment: The problem is, that there is not always just one package to provide a certain file or library. How should a build system know which piece of software to install? Thats a desicion that does not follow simple dependency tracking. Thats why it has to be distribution specific.

Answer (score 1):

i don't think such a thing is really feasible, so the short answer would be:

> no

the examples you mentioned are really tailored to build everything from scratch, hence you have a workflow that allows to do just that (build everything, including dependencies).

other distributions (like Debian and all it's derivatives) are focused more on downloading pre-compiled binaries (rather than building locally them from scratch), so they do not offer a framework to autocompile just the dependencies.

### update

as far as simply resolving dependencies for a given package, this is one of the main tasks the distribution *maintainers* are facing: find out which packages require which (versions of) libraries,...

since distributions put heavy *human* power into this task, i doubt whether it is automatable.

Comment: I doubt this is _the_ answer - in many cases `./configure --prefix=/opt && make && make install` works perfectly fine once all dependencies are resolved

Comment: @TobiasKienzler your answer is specifically about "automatically compile+install *dependencies*" of a given package; any call to `./configure` does *not* resolve any dependencies; it will simply compile+install the package itself (given all deps are resolved), which is really not what you asked. apart from that, not all packages use `autotools`.

Comment: what I meant was the major difficulty in _most_ cases lies in parsing `configure`'s error messages on missing dependencies and finding/downloading their source, and not necessarily in compiling/installing them (though if they're not using `autotools` _some_ metainformation à la `ebuild` or [GoboLinux recipes](http://www.gobolinux.org/?page=doc/articles/compile) needs to be obtained)

Comment: @TobiasKienzler the problem is, that in many (if not most) cases, the error-messages on missing dependencies are user-defined rather than standardized (thus hard to parse automatically); also some dependencies are *soft* (that is: the package will compile with missing features) but these may be *hard* dependencies for you (e.g. without those features the package is worthless for you).

Comment: Good point, though obviously it is silly to re-resolve dependencies that other distributions' maintainers already _did_ resolve - their resolution is potentially easier to adapt than stating from scratch

Comment: @TobiasKienzler also consider that the messages rarely provide you with the URL where you can download the source of the missing dependency, they just say "Error: missing library.X.so` or whatever. You then need to figure out what program provides that and go look for where to download it. Since these are not standardized, I doubt you can automate. The dependencies are explicitly listed by package name in arch packages, that's why `yaourt` can do it.

Comment: @terdon That's precisely what my question is about - a tool that, without being too distribution-specific, knows dependencies and where to obtain the dependency sources. That alone would save me a lot of work, and if it outputs a suggested compilation order / checklist I could still manually compile but no longer needed to hunt down `libWhatMe`'s source

Comment: @TobiasKienzler I know but I don't see how that could be possible without a centralized source repository with a specified format. If you just have the dev's configure script, you have no idea what error message he/she will choose to print so you can't automate parsing them. That's one of the main points of using distributions, they do that for you. Think about it, `libWhatMe` could be found at `libewhatme.com` or `sourceforge/libwhatme` or `libwhatme.org` or `libcompletelydifferent.com` or wherever, you can't know because there is no standard for this.

Comment: @terdon Indeed, but my point is there could (theoretically) be a tool which has that lookup integrated (or on a centralized server) - and that is something which could be independent of a distribution which then adds some patches to use the respective paths etc.

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to the other answer, such tools exist, though I haven't decided on one yet:

- [nix](http://nixos.org/nix/)
- [Zero Install](http://0install.net/)
- [pkgsrc](http://www.pkgsrc.org/)

While they include distributing precompiled binaries, they also allow for compilation.

Also cf. the question [Non-Root Package Managers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/5535/863)