# Automate chroot into broken system

Tags: grub, chroot

Every time you have to mount a system with a live-boot-CD and `chroot` into the system to repair grub, you have to type so many lines to mount into the right partition:

```
fdisk -l
```

find the right partition for example `/dev/sda1`

```
mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/
mount -t proc none /mnt/proc
mount -o bind /dev /mnt/dev
mount -t sysfs sys /mnt/sys
chroot /mnt/
```

Is there a way to optimize this with a single script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Copy this script as `mount-root` on your usb-device

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$(whoami &2>/dev/null)" != "root" ] && [ "$(id -un &2>/dev/null)" != "root" ] ; then
 echo "You must be root to run this script!"; echo "use 'sudo !!'"; exit 1
fi


if [ $# -ne 2 ]; then
 echo "calling this script with only two options with the device and mountpoint"
 echo "for example"
 echo "mount-root /dev/sda1 /media/other/"
 set -x
 fdisk -l
 lsblk -f
 exit
fi

D=$(echo $1 | sed 's:/$::')
M=$(echo $2 | sed 's:/$::')

echo mounting $D to $M

mkdir -p $M

mount $D $M
mount -t proc none $M/proc
mount -o bind /dev $M/dev
mount -t sysfs sys $M/sys
mount --bind /dev/pts $M/dev/pts
cp /proc/mounts $M/etc/mtab
chroot $M/ /bin/bash
```

source: https://gist.github.com/rubo77/eac3313ea5302acfca60

Comment: I am not sure about the `none` for proc or and tht there is no slash before `sys`?

Comment: I am not sure what / you are referring to.. (Also `devpts` is a filesystem like proc and sysfs: `mount -t devpts none $M/dev/pts`, though I don't think there's a difference in effect - see http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/98405/70524 ).